# Can't stop thread at all (unless I cause an exception)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, python-multithreading, pyserial

So I am working on a GUI (*PyQt5*) and I am multi-threading to be able to do data acquisition and real-time plotting concurrently.

Long story short, all works fine apart from stopping the thread that handles the data acquisition, which loops continuously and calls *PySerial* to read the com port. When a button on the GUI is pressed, I want to break the while loop within the thread so as to stop reading the com port and allow the com port to be closed safely.

Currently, none of the methods I have tried manage to gracefully exit the while loop inside the thread, which causes all kinds of errors with the *PySerial* library and the closed com port/ attempted reading in the thread. Here is what I have tried:

- Using a class variable (`self.serial_flag`) and changing its state when the button is pressed. The thread loop then looks like this: `while self.serial_flag:`
- Using a global variable (`serial_flag = False` at top of the script). Defining `global serial_flag` at the top of the threaded function and same condition: `while serial_flag:`
- Using a shared memory variable: `from multiprocessing import Value`, then defining `serial_flag = Value('i', 0)` then in the loop checking `while serial_flag.value == 0:`
- Using `threading.Event` to set an event and use that as a break condition. Defining: `serial_flag = threading.Event()` and inside the thread while loop: `if serial_flag.is_set(): break`

None of these seem to work in breaking the while loop and I promise I have done my homework in researching solutions for this type of thing - I feel like there is something basic that I am doing wrong with my multithreading application. Here are the parts of the GUI that call/ deal with the thread (with my latest attempt using threading.Event):

```
 import threading, queue
 serial_flag = threading.Event()

    def serial_run_data(self):
       cntr = 0
       while True:
           if serial_flag.is_set():
               print("flag was set")
               break

           value = self.ser.read_until(self.EOL)  # old EOL: \r\n, new: o\i
           if len(value) == 21 and self.EOL in value:
               self.queueRaw.put_nowait(value)
           else:
               print(value)

           cntr = cntr + 1
           if cntr == 50:
               self.data_ready = True
               cntr = 0

    def start_plot(self):  # Start/ Stop Button
       # Start Button
       if self.start_button.text() == 'START':
           self.serial_setup()
           if not self.error:
               self.serial_flag = True
               self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.serial_run_data)
               self.t.start()
               self.timer.start()
               self.start_button.setText('STOP')
       # Stop Button
       elif self.start_button.text() == 'STOP':
           if not self.error:
               self.serial_flag = False
               serial_flag.set()
               self.timer.stop()
               print(self.t.is_alive())
               self.ser.close()
               self.start_button.setText('START')
```

Any feedback is appreciated (I will make a minimally-reproducible example if what I have provided isn't sufficient). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are closing the serial port without waiting for the thread to terminate. Although you set the event, that part of the code might not be reached, since reading from the serial port is still happening. When you close the serial port, an error in the serial library occurs.

You should wait for the thread to terminate, then close the port, which you can do by adding

```
self.t.join()
```

after `serial_flag.set()`.

Comment: I have just attempted this unfortunately I am still getting the same issue. Heres the terminal dump: `Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juan/Desktop/Force Plate/FORCE PLATES/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 565, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout.time_left())
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: This looks like an error from the `serial` library and might not be connected to threading.

Comment: Correct Andre, but that issue is related to the thread not stopping and the com port being closed whilst the thread attempts to read from the serial port. If the thread was properly terminated, the debug message in `print("flag was set")` should've been printed. If I call a non-exist function such as self.t.quit(), it raises an exemption and the thread actually terminates properly, but that is barely a graceful way to handle this

Comment: Here is what I mean when I insert `self.t.quit()` after `serial_flag.set()`: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juan/Desktop/Force Plate/FORCE PLATES/venv/force_test.py", line 396, in start_plot
    self.t.quit()
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'quit'
flag was set`

Comment: Try adding `self.t.join()` after `serial_flag.set()` in order to wait for the thread to finish, then close the com port. It is possible that the thread is still reading from the com port, then you set the event in the main thread, which is not registered in the com port thread and when you close the port an error occurs.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much Andre. I will have to look up the .join() method again to fully understand why that makes this work properly as compared to before

Comment: Glad to help :) `Thread.join` is basically a blocking call that blocks until the thread terminates. It is used in cases like this when you need to wait for thread to finish, before your other code can execute. Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

Comment: Yep of course, it never occurred to me that the thread termination 'overhead' could delay past the next call in the main thread - one of many considerations required for multithreading I guess... Thanks again!